# problema al recuperar imagen de carpeta para mostrarla, no la encientra

Tags: php, html, mysql

mi problema es que cuando cargo una imagen aun na carpeta si guarda en la carpeta desde el formulario, pero cuano la quiero leer no la localiza  y no s ecual es el problema si en mi bd se esta guardando la direccion de la carpeta en donde se aloja mi imagen este es el codigo qu tengo para guardar la imagen en la carpeta desde php:

```
$extension = '';
$ruta ='imgProductos';
$archivo = $_FILES['fotoPro']['tmp_name'];// el archivoq ue biene desde el formulario
$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['fotoPro']['name'];
$info = pathinfo($nombre_archivo);

 if ($archivo != ''){

    $extension=$info['extension'];
    if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension=="JPG" || $extension=="PNG" || $extension =="png" ){

     move_uploaded_file($archivo,'imgProductos/'.$nombrePro.'.'.$extension);
      $ruta = $ruta."/".$nombrePro.".".$extension;

    }else{
        header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=el formato no es valido&c=prod&p=altap&t=error');

        exit;
   }


 }else {
   $ruta="imgProductos/sinFoto.PNG";
}
```

y ese codigo me envia la imagen con el nombre del producto q se introdujo a esta carpeta: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta y todo bien seguarda la imagen en la carpeta y en la bd si seguarda el directorio d ela imagen  asi semuestran los datos guardados en mi bd: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL PROBLEMA ESTA EN LA ORA DE CUANDO QUIERO RECUPERAR MI IMAGEN PARA MOSTRARLA Y ME EDADO CUENTA QUE CUANDO MANDO ATRAER ALA IMAGEN EN D ELA BD NO LA JALA Y LAS DEMAS ANTERIORES SI Y SI CUMPLE CON EL FORMATO QUE SE PIDE, NOS EPOR Q CUANDO CAMBI LA CARPETA imgProductos, si s emuestran las imagenes y despues s erepite el error vuelvo aguaradr otro producto y no muetsra su imagen hasta que cambio la carpeta de lugar a que se devera este erroro  no entiendeo saludos espero me puedan asesorar este es el codgo dond emando atraer mi imagen para mostrarla:

```
<div class=" row">
                                                        <?php  $sel=$con->prepare("SELECT*FROM Producto where cod_catego1 =5 ");
                                                        $sel->execute();
                                                        $res=$sel->get_result();
                                                        $row=mysqli_num_rows($res);

                                                        while($f=$res->fetch_assoc()){

                                                         ?>
                                                        <div class="card col s3 ">
                                                            <form action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $f["modelo"]; ?>" method="post" class="for1">
                                                                <div class="card-image">
                                                                <img src="<?php echo $f['imagen'] ?>" width="50" height="180">
                                                                <!-- <span class="card-title">Card Title</span> -->
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="card-content  purple-text">
                                                                    <p><?php echo $f['nombrep'] ?></p>
                                                                    <p><?php echo $f['modelo'] ?></p>
                                                                </div>

                                                                <!-- <div class="card-action"> -->
                                                                    <input type="number"  value="1" name="quantity" min="1"  class=" col s6 blue-text" autocomplete="off">
                                                                 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $f["nombrep"]; ?>" />
                                                                 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $f["precio"]; ?>" />
                                                                 <button class="btn btn-floating orange" type="submit" name="add_to_cart"><i class="material-icons right">add_shopping_cart</i></button>
                                                                    <button data-target="modal1" data-id="<?php echo $f["cod_producto"]; ?>"  value="<?php echo $f["modelo"]; ?>"  class="btn modal-trigger ver"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></button>
                                                                    <div class="card-content">
                                                                        <p class="red-text "><?php echo "$ ".number_format($f['precio'],2); ?></p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </form>

                                                            <!-- </div> -->

                                                        </div>

                                                        <?php

                                                    }
                                                    $sel->close();
                                                        $con->close();
                                                    ?>

                        </div><!-- fin de row container de pruductos-->
```

y asi se muestran algunas imagenes y otras no, así se ve al ejecutar mi pagina web solo captura mis imagenes ya guardadas anterior mente y las nuevas no, saludos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo no recomiendo guardar la ruta si no.mas bien solo el nombre, de esa manera se maneja la ruta directamente en el html, que pasaría si por x razón debes mover la carpeta de sitio? El update a tu base seria un infierno, por otro lado no se como estés manejando la estructura de tus archivos para saber a quien nivel del directorio esta el que carga las imágenes en comparación con el directorio de imágenes, muestra la estructura a ver

Comment: Ahora si le das clic derecho sobre la imagen faltante, que ruta te esta imprimiendo?